# Unhashable type error trying to pass list to function in python

Tags: python

I've got this function which is meant to calculate the equivalent number from a roman numeral, where the numeral is passed to the function as a list where each numeral is separate:

```
def numerals_operations(*args): 
    n = len(args) - 1
    result = numerals[args[n]]
    for keys in range(n):
        key_1 = args[n]
        key_2 = args[n - 1]
        if numerals[key_1] > numerals[key_2]:
            result -= numerals[key_2]
        else:
            result += numerals[key_2]
        n -= 1
    return result
```

When I try to call the function on a list, I get this error: 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'list''. I think it's because using *args means the function will be expecting a tuple, but I don't know how long the list getting passed to the function will be. What should the function parameter be so that it can be called on a list of unknown length? Thanks.

Comment: You have to unpack the list when calling the function: `numerals_operations(*lst)` else `lst` will be placed in the tuple `args`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thankyou so much! Such a simple fix.